# How to create custom attributes for a custom component that can be assigned from XML in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am implementing a custom component and trying to take input from XML for an attribute. In Android, it looks something like this

```xml
<it.beppi.arcpageindicator.ArcPageIndicator
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   app:apiViewPager="@id/view_pager"
   app:apiArcOrientation="toDown"
   app:apiAnimationType="cover"
   />
```

How can I do this in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: You need to customize the label app (the name can be customized) in the root layout of the XML file. The format is:
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos-auto"`,and the code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectionalLayout
    xmlns:ohos="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos-auto"
    ......
    >
</DirectionalLayout>
```

**Step 2**: When `ArcPageIndicator` is used in the XML file, define the line custom attribute `apiArcOrientation`. The code is as follows:

```
<!--com.huawei.flowlayout.library is the package path of the FlowLayout class ---->
<com.huawei.flowlayout.library.FlowLayout
    ......
    app:apiArcOrientation="toDown"
    />
```

**Step 3**: Obtain the attribute value through AttrSet in the Java code. The code is as follows:

```
public ArcPageIndicator(Context context, AttrSet attrSet) {
    ......
    String apiArcOrientation = attrSet.getAttr("apiArcOrientation").get().getStringValue();
}
```